# Using the laws, show that (A-B)-C is a subset of A-C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Working out of chapter two of my textbook and I am not seeing how I can relate laws to this question as it only deals with unions and intersections. So my attempt at proving this is as follows,

- $A=\{x\mid x\in A \land x\notin B \land x\notin C\}$
- $(A-B) \subset A$
- $(A-B)-C \subset A $
- $(A-C) \subset A$

Comment: You should make sure that the question is repeated in the body of the question too.

Answer (score 2):

$(A-B)$ is the set of elements that are in $A$ but not in $B$

$(A-C)$ is the set of elements in $A$ but not in $C$

$(A-B)-C$ is  the set of  elements that are in $(A-B)$ but not in $C$. Note that if an element is in $(A-B)$ it is in $A$.

So if an element is in $(A-B)-C)$ it is in A but not in C. therefore it is an element of $(A-C)$ this proves the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your first bullet point does not describe $A$, but rather $(A-B)-C$. Starting from there you could see that dropping the condition $x\notin B$ gives you $A-C$ and you are done.
Otherwise note as in your other bullet points that $(A-B)-C\subseteq A-B\subseteq A$ and of course $(A-B)-C$ is disjoint to $C$. But these two facts already say that it is a subset of $A-C$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(A - B) - C = (A \cap B^c) \cap C^c \supseteq A \cap C^c = A-C$$

In general, switching to intersection notation tends to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

What it comes down to is that if $U\subset A$, then $U - C \subset A - C$.

Then take $U = A-B$. I think you'll agree it's obvious that $U\subset A$ (that's just saying $A-B\subset A$).

So you can conclude that $U-C \subset A-C$, *i.e.*, $\boxed{(A-B)-C \subset A-C}$ as desired.